# In Django app models, how to get the url prefix

Tags: django

I am writing a Django blog app named `blogengine`
in the root `urls.py`:

```
url(r'^blog/', include('blogengine.urls')),
```

In my `blogengine/models.py`

```
class Post(models.Model):
    title = models.CharField(max_length=200)
    pub_date = models.DateTimeField()
    text = models.TextField()

    def get_absolute_url(self):
        return "/blog/post/%s/" % self.id
```

Here I defined a function `get_absolute_url` with a hard coding `/blog/` prefix.
How could I prevent this hard code and using some way to get the prefix in `ROOT_URLCONF`

Comment: Thanks all your answers, it helps a lot. I can use the reverse resolution in both python and template code by naming the url dispatcher, and then remove the hard code :)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use reverse resolution of named url. Here is the link to the detail https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/1.8/topics/http/urls/#reverse-resolution-of-urls

Here is the example.

```
url(r'^post/(?P<id>\d+)/$', post_view, name='post_detail'),
```

This is the model.
from django.core

```
from django.core.urlresolvers import reverse

class Post(models.Model):
    title = models.CharField(max_length=200)
    pub_date = models.DateTimeField()
    text = models.TextField()

    def get_absolute_url(self):
        return reverse('post_detail', kwargs={'id': self.id})
```

Answer (score 1):

No, this is absolutely not the way to do it. Your model should not care at all about the prefix.

Instead you should use the provided `reverse` function to calculate the URL, whatever the prefix:

```
def get_absolute_url(self):
    return reverse('blog-post', kwargs={'id': self.id})
```

Answer (score 1):

get_absolute_url() is not necessary:

```
url(r'^blog/$', views.post_list, name='post_list'),
url(r'^blog/(?P<post_id>[\w+-]*)/$', views.post_detail, name='post_detail')
```